# how to fix opencv cv2 ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, import

I installed opencv library by using "pip install opencv-python", but ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' error message came out. So I tried to install in anaconda prompt, and I installed opencv-python again, but it stilll didn't work. vscode, python version 3.8.

[terminal capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xskYx.png)
I went to opencv github site, and I knew that I had to install only one option of opencv package. so I removed all of opencv packages and installed opencv-python again, but it didnt work.....ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'... how can I import cv2?

Comment: Please visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the terminal output, the basic pip you use is the one from Python3.8 installed on your computer `pip 23.1.2 from C:\users\...\python38\libsite-packages\pip (python 3.8)`.

But you try to run your program from Python3.9 `& C:\users\...\python39\python.exe`. The installed modules are not available for the other versions of python installed, so if you want the program to work you will have to either launch your program with python 3.8, or install opencv with your python 3.9 pip.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to run your code by `python3.9` but you are installing opencv via on `python3.8`. To be sure which python version is used for pip you can run the command:

```
which python
```

Also you can still run the code via on `Python3.9`. All you need to do is that installing opencv by python3.9:

```
python3.9 -m pip install opencv-python
```

This command is helpfull when you need to install a package for a specific python version.

Answer (score 0):

You install the `opencv` package in the **python 38** environment, but use **pyth 39** to execute the code, of course you will get errors.

[image]

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Select Interpreter` to select the correct interpreter (*Or click on the current python version shown in the lower right corner.*)

[image]

[image]

and then run the script through the triangle button in the upper right corner.

[image]

[Follow this doc to start using python in vscode.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)

[More information about the python environment.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)